# How big can the 8-bit CPU (8086) support?

Tags: cpu

I have a 8-bit Famiclone, which has its only DOS.. just wondering how much memory in theory can it support?

https://helloacm.com/the-8-bit-dos-by-famicom-clone-bbgdos-in-the-1990s/